# Parsing an XML file with Nokogiri SAX parser

Tags: ruby, arrays, xml, nokogiri, saxparser

I have done some reading and I have been trying to get certain data from a large XML file. 
The data looks like this:

```
<Provider ID="0042100323">
    <Last_Name>LastName</Last_Name>
    <First_Name>FirstName</First_Name>
    <Mdl_Name>Middle</Mdl_Name>
    <Gndr>M</Gndr>
</Provider>
```

I would like to write the `start_element` to add all of these to a record array like:

```
0042100323, LastName, FirstName, Middle, M
```

using something like:

```
def start_element name, attributes = []
    @@records << attributes[0][1] if name == "Provider"
end
```

How can I update my code to add the other tags to the array?

Comment: How big is the XML file? What we used to consider big, and warranted using a SAX parser, is now medium sized and can easily be handled using a DOM-parser.

Comment: I tried running it using the DOM-parser. The file itself doesn't seem like it would be that large @190MB. But I do run into errors when trying to parse it without the SAX parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`characters`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Document#characters-instance_method) event to get text inside tag:

```
def characters(string)
  @records << string
end
```

**UPDATE** according to OP's comment:

to grab text selectively according to the containing tag; remember the last seen tag, and grab text only if the last seen tag is what you want.

```
def start_element(name, attributes = [])
  @records << attributes[0][1] if name == "Provider"
  @last_seen_tag = name
end

def characters(string)
  if ['Last_Name', 'First_Name', 'Mdl_Name', 'Gndr'].include? @last_seen_tag
    @records << string
  end
end

def end_element name
  @last_seen_tag = nil
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to only grab the tags I need? The data I gave was the data I need, but the XML itself has a lot more fields than what I listed. I added the characters event and it started grabbing the strings within every tag in the XML file.

Comment: @ToddJ., I updated the answer according to your comment. Also I updated the code to use instance variable instead of class variable.

Comment: this has helped me to make a lot of progress in my project. thank you so much!

Comment: To clarify though, the script is currently adding the id, first, last, middle, gender as separate entries. can i combine them somehow or change the method of adding them?

Comment: @ToddJ., I'm not sure I understood you correctly. Do you want something like this? http://pastebin.com/Nquy9VrP

Comment: Yes exactly :) thank you for your help! it is my understanding that line 2 creates an entry in an array, then line 8 adds anything specified in line 7 to the array, then line 14 adds everything so far into another array as a single entry? (it is working, i'm just trying to learn why)

Comment: @ToddJ., `@fields` is a temporary array. It's first created seeing `Provider` tag, texts are appended, and when `Provider` tag end, the temporary array is appended to the result `@record`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the below approach :-

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-EOT
<Provider ID="0042100323">
    <Last_Name>LastName</Last_Name>
    <First_Name>FirstName</First_Name>
    <Mdl_Name>Middle</Mdl_Name>
    <Gndr>M</Gndr>
</Provider>
EOT

def start_element name, attributes = [], childs = []
  node = @doc.at("//*[local-name()='#{name}']")
  contents_of_childs = node.search("./child::*").each_with_object([]) do |n, a|
    a << n.text if childs.include?(n.name)
  end
  attributes.each_with_object([]) do |attr, a|
    a << node[attr] unless node[attr].nil?
  end + contents_of_childs
end

start_element('Provider', ['ID'], %w(Last_Name First_Name Mdl_Name Gndr))
# => ["0042100323", "LastName", "FirstName", "Middle", "M"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Variation to `Arup`s answer:

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-EOT
<Provider ID="0042100323">
    <Last_Name>LastName</Last_Name>
    <First_Name>FirstName</First_Name>
    <Mdl_Name>Middle</Mdl_Name>
    <Gndr>M</Gndr>
</Provider>
EOT

(@doc.at("//Provider")["ID"] + @doc.text).split 
 #=> ["0042100323", "LastName", "FirstName", "Middle", "M"]
```